# Why should transcendental functions and their arguments be dimensionless?

Tags: functions, transcendental-equations

While looking for the answer on the internet I came across an answer giving this explanation
 "Another way of seeing clearly why an exponential's argument should be dimensionless is to Taylor expand: $\exp(x)=1+x+x^2/2+\cdots$ Every term has a different dimension if x is dimensionful, and hence cannot be summed."

But this is not a proof in the sense we do in mathematics!
So can anyone provide with a mathematically sound proof?

Comment: Suppose you're calculating $\exp(5m) = 1 + 5\text{ m} + \dfrac{25 \text{ sq m}}{2!} + \dfrac{125 \text{ cubic m}}{3!}+\cdots$ And adding $5$meters to $12.5$ sq. meters doesn't make sense, right?

Comment: Also every function can be expressed with sum of infinite exponential functions or sinusoidal functions satisfying certain conditions.

Comment: This is perhaps not a proof, but Buckingham's pi theorem states that any physically meaningful relation between physical variables can be restated as a relation between dimensionless combinations of the variables. When you do that, of course any transcendental function ends up taking dimensionless quantitites. – On a side note, this is why one often prefers the form $\ln(Cx)$ over $\ln(x)+C$ for the indefinite integral of $1/x$. If $x$ has a unit, the integration constant can be taken to have the inverse unit, leaving a dimensionless argument to the logarithm.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Good point with the $\ln(Cx)$. Personally, when these forms appear in the physical sciences, typically as a solution of a differential equation, I prefer to avoid constants of integration by evaluating definite integrals on both sides. That way, the issue of introducing constants of whatever dimension is eliminated, or at least hidden away.

Answer (score 4):

No proof is needed, it's true simply by definition of units. When dealing with units in any physics calculation, we generally respect the following unofficial axioms that define units:

1) A unit is treated as a variable in any calculation

2) Any number that is linear in a specific unit (with no intercept) is said to be a quantity of "those units".

So if "m" is a unit, that means that we can only classify a quantity as having "units of m" if it is of the form $k \text{m}$ for some unitless number $k$. Respecting the definition above, we see that $x = e^{2 \text{m}} = 1 + 2 \text{m} + 2 \text{m}^2 + \frac{4}{3} \text{m}^3 + \cdots$ is not strictly of form $k \text{m}$, thus by the definition above, it can't be said to have "units of m".

Aside from that definition, I don't think "units" has a formal definition in pure mathematics (perhaps someone will point me out wrong here), so without that formal definition, you can't make a proof. You need a definition like the one I wrote above.

Comment: While I am a little out of my element, I would think different "units" describing a property can be related by linear transformations in $\mathbf{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the equation of motion

$s(t) = s(0) + v(0) t + \frac{a}{2} t^2$

as a Taylor expansion of the function $s(t)$ around $t=0$, exact for constant acceleration. The coefficients of this series are $s(0)$, $v(0)$ and $a$ ($=a(0)$) and have different units.

When you expand a function $f(x)$ in Taylor series, the coefficients are given by

$a_n = \frac{1}{n!} \left[\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}\right]_{x=x_0}$

and so they have units of $f$, $f/x$, $f/x^2$, $f/x^3$, etc.

So, the correct expansion of $exp(x)$ for $x$ in meters is

$exp(x) = 1 m + x + \frac{1}{2m} x^2 + \frac{1}{6m^2} x^3 + ... $

For instance,

$exp(2m) = 1 m + 2m + \frac{1}{2m} 4 m^2 + \frac{1}{6m^2} 8 m^3 + ... $

If you want to keep the expansion as simple as

$exp(x) = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ... $,

you'd better have a dimensionless $x$.

Besides, a unit should be treated as a multiplication factor. Different functions treats multiplied factors different ways. For example,

$log(4.18 J) = log(4.18) + log(J)$ and

$e^{4.18 J} = (e^{J})^{4.18} = (e^{4.18})^{J}$.

That's too complicated and usually avoided in formulas of natural sciences.

In some equations involving entropy, the logarithm is divided as in $log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)$, such that the arguments $a$ and $b$ are dimensional. The Wikipedia page [[Sackur-Tetrode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation)][1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation) has an example of such equations, but also a justification for it:

> Strictly speaking, the use of dimensioned arguments to the logarithms
> is incorrect, however their use is a "shortcut" made for simplicity.
> If each logarithmic argument were divided by an unspecified standard
> value expressed in terms of an unspecified standard mass, length and
> time, these standard values would cancel in the final result, yielding
> the same conclusion. The individual entropy terms will not be
> absolute, but will rather depend upon the standards chosen, and will
> differ with different standards by an additive constant.