Where are the units of the box counting fractal dimension?
The box counting dimension of a bounded set $E$, as defined on Wikipedia is defined as:
$$D=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\log{N(\epsilon)}}{\log{(1/\epsilon)}},$$
where $N$ is the number of boxes of size $\epsilon$ needed to cover $E$.  However, the size of the box has units. If we have a shape in 2D,  then the box has units of $m^2$, where $m$  is a meter.  So does this definition of $D$ have nonsensical units?  Is this problem solved by the Hausdorff dimension, which appears to be a more rigorous way of doing the same calculation?

Where did you find this definition? Normally it would be $D = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\log N}{\log (1/\epsilon)}$. Also notice that both the numerator and denominator have the same units so $D$ itself it unitless.

How are the units the same?  N has no unit, it is counting number, and epsilon has units of area.  What am I getting wrong here?  I did rewrite the definition as per your points.

The size of $N$ is based on $\epsilon$ so it has units boxes per $\epsilon$. Then you divide by the per $epsilon$ term to get a final unit of boxes, which is unitless.

I don't think I agree.  I edited my expression of the box counting dimension to match exactly what is on Wikipedia.  It is true that N is a function of $\epsilon$, but that doesn't mean that it has units of $\epsilon$.

The idea is that the calculation should be done with $\epsilon$ a pure number, i.e. with the value of the measurement. Equivalently (and you can do this more or less every time you use $g(\epsilon)$, you could fix a "reference unit" $u_0$ and consider $\log\frac1{\epsilon/u_0}$. This is independent of the unit. If you choose a different $u'_0$ the new value becomes $\log\frac1{\epsilon/u'_0}=\log\frac1{\epsilon/u_0}+\log\frac{u'_0}{u_0}$ which diverge to $-\infty$ in the same way as $\log\frac1{\epsilon/u_0}$.

OK, a reference unit could be inserted and that would solve the problem.  I guess most people assume this is obvious, and they just don't bother including the reference unit.

Mathematics is all done with pure numbers; the metrological details are usually left to the physicists.

Ha ha.  But in the case of the box counting dimension, the suggestion is that this is an actual measurement to be performed in the physical world, and I would argue that in this case it should have correct units.

@Chris Duly noted.

Ummm... what do you think are the "units" when we talk about a plane being two-dimensional, a cube being three-dimensional, and so on?

meters squared?

@SassatelliGiulio. Thanks for printout out the reference or normalizing unit.  I have discovered that I in fact need this reference unit to complete the mathematical derivation I'm working on.  It turns out that this unit isn't just a metrological detail, I would argue.

(1) $\log$ is a transcendental function.  The argument and output of transcendental functions are typically treated as unitless.  See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/954127/ .  See also https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/a-mathematical-formalisation-of-dimensional-analysis/ .  Dimension is unitless.  (2) $\varepsilon$ is always a length (typically thought of as the diameter of a box, or the radius of a ball), i.e. it has units of length.  $N(\varepsilon)$ has units of "boxes" (it is a count).


So does this definition of D have nonsensical units?

As hinted by the base of logs not being specified, arguably an information theoretical perspective here could be useful; $\log(N_\epsilon(A))$ then could be interpreted as the amount of information (this being a scalar quantity) one obtains if one learns how many pixels of scale $1/\epsilon$ hit $A$. The denominator $\log(1/\epsilon)$ similarly is the amount of information one obtains if one learns if a pixel of scale $1/\epsilon$ is black as opposed to white. The ratio is then the amount of information one obtains if one learns how many pixels of scale $1/\epsilon$ hit $A$, given that the amount of information one obtains if one learns if a pixel of scale $1/\epsilon$ is black as opposed to white is normalized to be $1$ (or alternatively one can note that the ratio is equal to $\log_{1/\epsilon}(N_\epsilon(A))$). Note that in this interpretation $D$ becomes a pure number.
(I am teaching a class this semester that is somewhat related to these ideas; see e.g. https://youtu.be/ei-RND8EmQc?feature=shared&t=1165 for more.)


Is this problem solved by the Hausdorff dimension, which appears to be a more rigorous way of doing the same calculation?

It should be noted that Hausdorff dimension is not any more rigorous than Minkowski dimension(s), insofar as one accounts for the involved limit not existing by switching to limit superior and limit inferior.
In fact, there is a reformulation of Hausdorff and upper/lower Minkowski dimensions which indicates that they can be interpolated. And indeed, for any $\theta\in[0,1]$, there are two "intermediate dimensions" $\underline{\dim}_\theta$ and $\overline{\dim}_\theta$ such that
$$\underline{\dim}_0=\overline{\dim}_0=\dim_H,\quad\underline{\dim}_1=\underline{\dim}_M,\quad \overline{\dim}_0=\overline{\dim}_M.$$
(See e.g. Falconer, Fraser & Kempton's paper "Intermediate Dimensions".)
It should also be noted that Hausdorff and Minkowski dimensions are in general not the same numbers.
